# how to use jquery greater than selector with current nav

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a nav with a current class added to the li if it's selected. 
I am using this Plugin too (http://trevordavis.net/blog/jquery-one-page-navigation-plugin
).

When there is a `.current` class on the `<li>` it changes color and I want to make all the `<li>`'s greater than the current one change color too.

I'm guessing I will have to find out if the `<li>` has the `.current` class and if so add `.current` class to all the `<li>`'s greater than that one as well?

code example which is the same as the example from the plugin above
(http://jsfiddle.net/A5VTX/)

Comment: Please include code in your question.

Comment: greater than you mean next siblings?

Comment: greater than as in all the li's above the current li

Comment: Try `$(".current").prevAll("li").addClass("current")`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using jQuery that I believe implements what you desire.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/whAIL

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  var active = $('li.active'),
      items = $('li.item'),
      beginSlice = items.index(active);

  var selection = items.slice(beginSlice);
  selection.css('color', 'red');  
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/A5VTX/1/

I've applied to my example but it doesn't seem it work

Comment: It works if you assign an initial `.current` class on one of your `li` items.

Comment: cool thanks this is correct but need to reverse the selected color back to normal when it is not current li or above

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
$("li.current").nextUntil("ul").css("color", "[whatever]");
```

If you're referring to "greater than" being all previous items, simply change the code to:

```
$("li.current").prevUntil("ul").css("color", "[whatever");
```

These solutions assume you don't already have a CSS class defined. That would be preferred, and the code would be:

```
$("li.current").nextUntil("ul").addClass("[whatever]"); // or use .prevUntil
```

Comment: I had to on my local computer and it works but i need to target the a child tag and also remove the css/ class when scrolled back to the top. This is an example but some reason the underline css doesn't show in jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/A5VTX/16/